# FXML file loads but does not display in scene

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to make it so when a user clicks on an item in my listView, it loads a new scene. The listView is a child of another scene, and I'm essentially trying to swap the listView scene with another scene. When attempting this, the FXML files is loaded (as indicated through the console), but it does not appear in my GUI.

Here is the code for the Main class which has the stage (where the original scene is stored)

```
package Controllers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import util.Album;
import util.Artist;
import util.FileSystem;
import util.Song;

public class Main extends Application{

    private Stage mainStage = new Stage();
    private BorderPane mainLayout;
    private MainController mainController;
    private Scene scene;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Music Player");
        showMainView();
}

public void showMainView() throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));

        mainLayout = loader.load();

        scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show();
    }
```

Here is the Main Controller which is trying to call the XML file.

```
package Controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import util.*;

public class MainController {
     @FXML private ImageView nowPlayingImage;
     @FXML private Label nowPlayingSong;

     @FXML private HBox mediaControls; 
     @FXML private SVGPath shuffleButton;  
     @FXML private SVGPath repeatButton;  
     @FXML private SVGPath playButton;  
     @FXML private SVGPath pauseButton;   
     @FXML private SVGPath skipForward;  
     @FXML private SVGPath queueButton;  
     @FXML private Slider timeSlider; 
     @FXML private VBox playlists; 
     @FXML private VBox artists;
     @FXML private VBox albums; 
     @FXML private VBox songs;
     @FXML private TextField searchBar;
     @FXML private HBox subView;

     private Main main = new Main();
     private MusicPlayer music = new MusicPlayer();



    public void playListsScene(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Test Text");

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void artistsScene(MouseEvent event) throws Exception {
        ListView scene2 = new ListView();
        scene2= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Artists.fxml"));
        subView.getChildren().setAll(scene2);
    }

    public void setSubView() {
        try {

            BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
            pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ArtistSub.fxml"));
            subView.getChildren().setAll(pane);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the ArtistController which loads the listView

```
package Controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import util.Album;
import util.Artist;
import util.FileSystem;
import util.Song;

public class ArtistController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Artist> artistList;
    private Song selectedSong;
    private Album selectedAlbum;
    private Artist selectedArtist;

    public FileSystem file = new FileSystem();

    public void initialize() {
        ObservableList<Artist> artists = file.getArtists();
        artistList.setItems(artists);
        /*
        int limit = artists.size();
        for(int i=0; i<artists.size(); i++) {
            String artist = artists.get(i).toString();
            System.out.println(artist);
            artistList.getItems().add(artist);
        }
        */
        artistList.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {

             if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                 selectedArtist=artistList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                 /*
                 ObservableList<Song> songs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                 ObservableList<Album> albums = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                 for (Album album : selectedArtist.getAlbums()) {
                     albums.add(album);
                     songs.addAll(album.getSongs());
                 }
                 */
                try {
                    MainController main = new MainController();
                    System.out.println("test");
                    main.setSubView();



                } catch (Exception e) {

                }


             }
        });
    }



}
```

I'm still new to javafx, so I hope I'm not missing anything big that would be causing this issue.

Comment: Please try updating your question with a [mcve]. I do not see a `ListView` in your code here at all.

Comment: Why are you initialize the variables just to replace them immediately with the result of loading an fxml? Not an issue breaking the program, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: Just added where `ListView` is stored, hopefully that helps solve the issue @Zephyr